# Firebase auth won't send otp in signed apk

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I've searched about this and I know its been asked here a lot but hear me out. I created my firebase project via the Assistant within the Android studio. I'm using Firebase phone auth in my app and its working completely fine when debugging. But it is *not* working when I generate a signed apk for debug release (haven't uploaded my app to playstore yet.)

Now a lot of the answers on SO say that you need to put your SHA-1 in your firebase project. I already have the SHA-1 because it was created by the assistant, see:

[image]

Moreover, I added my SHA-256 from `signinReport` option in Gradle but phone auth is still not working when in my signed apk. I have to send the apk to a client, please help!

Comment: add SHA-1 of debug and release. No need to add SHA-256

Comment: How do I find my SHA-1 of my debug release?

Comment: https://medium.com/pen-bold-kiln-press/sha-1-android-studio-ec02fb893e72
You can try this.